# webpack: transpile web workers in public folder

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, web-worker, webpack-5

I'm next js for my project and it uses webpack 5 to compile typescript codes

I have several web worker scripts inside my public folder under path "/workers/**/*.worker.js"

I was wondering if I can write them in typescript too
or at least use babel to transpile them for es5 (for old browsers)

I know that anything under the "public" folder is served as is and as a file (like a CDN)

can I add a "workers" folder to my project and load them in the public path with webpack and next js?

Comment: I think you should be able to, why not!!! What is the problem you are running into when you try and do so?

Comment: @NalinRanjan I was looking for some resources to read and get started on that. I've never done something like this before

Comment: Webpack [Entry Point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

Comment: I suggest you try to come-up with a webpack config that generates bundles from typescript source files and put them under `public/workers` folder. Once you have that, then think of integrating with your existing project's build script(s). Also note, while compiling typescript sources that are supposed to run under the context of `webworker`, even the typescript-compiler options will be different a little, so make sure you keep this under a separate config file, say `worker.tsconfig.json`...

Comment: If you have a source repo that you can share, it will be really best to help you out.. if you can...

Comment: Webpack [Typescript](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)

Comment: We can specify a [custom tsconfig.json](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configfile) file for [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)

Comment: [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) option in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @nalin-ranjan I've come up with the solution

in my "next.config.js" I added a rule to my webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.worker\.ts$/,
      type: 'asset/resource',
      generator: {
        filename: 'static/[hash:5].[name].js',
      },
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            configFile: __dirname + '/worker.tsconfig.json',
          },
        },
      ],
    })
    return config
  },
}
```

with this rule, I could require my workers and use them as URLs and transpile typescript

also, I had to add a new "tsconfig" that had "isolatedModules" option disabled (because web workers are not modules). for that, I created an identical tsconfig file to next.js but disabled isolatedModules. the reason being that next.js forbids you to disable isolatedModules and resets it back

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore with Next.js v12.1.4